# How can I get my status (String) to blink in my batch file?

Tags: batch-file, time, colors, countdown

I'd like my string to blink in my batch file. The below works well for me. My job's computer logs me out soon after the 11th hour so I like a visual fair warning for that so my batch file does that. Below is my code so far but my string status doesn't blink.

```
@Echo off
mode 22,15
Color B
cls
set /a Minutes=0
set /a Time=0
Set /a Hours=0
Set /a Reset=11
set Str=Good
For /F "Tokens=*" %%I in ('Time /T') Do Set mytime=%%I

:hi
cls
Echo.
Echo Started %mytime%
Echo Status: %Str%
Echo.
Echo Time so far:
Echo.
Echo %Hours% Hours 
Echo.
Echo %Minutes% Minutes 
Echo.
Echo %Time% Seconds
Echo.
Echo %Reset% Hours to Reset


ping localhost -n 2 >nul
set /a time=%time%+1
if %time%==60 (
goto min
)else goto :hi


:min
set /a Time=0
set /a Minutes=%Minutes%+1
if %Minutes%==60 (
goto hours
)else goto :hi
goto hi


:hours
set /a Minutes=0
Set /a Reset=%Reset%-1
set /a Hours=%Hours%+1
if %Hours%==11 (
color 47 
set Str=ResetEmement
) else goto :hi
goto hi
```

Comment: Misspelled "im·mi·nent" lol

Comment: Feel free to edit your question instead of posting comments about it.

Comment: Your question is very vague and really doesn't explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Here are a few batch scripts that may be of interest to you. [Batch Clock Widget](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5028). It has an alarm and timer. Or this one: [Visualize a clock](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8546)